Use dependency injection in Azure logic app custom code
I created a azure logic app workspace with custom code through visual studio code. The code looks like a .net 8 isolated azure function. I can successfully run the function in workflow actions.
The next step is to implement the dependency injection. For Azure function in isolated model (which this is the type), I should have a host configuration in Program.cs. But I don't have this file. I also tried to create Startup.cs which works in process model. It doesn't work either. And I suspect the host build process is encapsulated in a process called 'Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.Functions.CustomCodeNetFxWorker.exe'. Hence, I cannot register anything in service collection. Now the only registered object is ILoggerFactory.
Any light?
Any help would be appreciated.
Reproduce steps:

Open Visual Studio Code. (With Azure logic app, auzurite installed.)

Create Azure logic app workspace in Azure extension.

Choose logic app with custom project and use the default values for the rest.

There is only when example function in this project.
namespace My.Fun
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.Workflows;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the function flow invoked function.
    /// </summary>
    public class function
    {
        private readonly ILogger<function> logger;

        public function(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<function>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the logic app workflow.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="zipCode">The zip code.</param>
        /// <param name="temperatureScale">The temperature scale (e.g., Celsius or Fahrenheit).</param>
        [Function("function")]
        public Task<Weather> Run([WorkflowActionTrigger] int zipCode, string temperatureScale)
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation("Starting function with Zip Code: " + zipCode + " and Scale: " + temperatureScale);

            // Generate random temperature within a range based on the temperature scale
            Random rnd = new Random();
            var currentTemp = temperatureScale == "Celsius" ? rnd.Next(1, 30) : rnd.Next(40, 90);
            var lowTemp = currentTemp - 10;
            var highTemp = currentTemp + 10;

            // Create a Weather object with the temperature information
            var weather = new Weather()
            {
                ZipCode = zipCode,
                CurrentWeather = $"The current weather is {currentTemp} {temperatureScale}",
                DayLow = $"The low for the day is {lowTemp} {temperatureScale}",
                DayHigh = $"The high for the day is {highTemp} {temperatureScale}"
            };

            return Task.FromResult(weather);
        }


As observed, ILogger is registered and ready to use. But there is no Startup.cs or Program.cs to update function host.



anyone has updates on this?
